# Pass custom text to datatable "Sort by" select label

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the Vuetify datatable for my project. Based on the sample from the docs

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#usage

if you toggle to a device screen size the component will render a select for item sorting:

[image]

I want to pass a customized for the "Sort by" text. I was able to figure out how to customize most of the texts

```
no-data-text="My custom no data text"
no-results-text="My custom no results text"
:footer-props="{
  showFirstLastPage: true,
  itemsPerPageText: 'My custom items per page',
  itemsPerPageOptions: [10, 20, -1],
  itemsPerPageAllText: 'My all text',
  pageText: '{0} - {1} of {2}'
}"
```

but I wasn't able to figure out where to pass in a custom text for this "Sort by" label. Would someone mind telling me how to customize that?

Comment: Looks like **no way** to translate by props. create-a-translation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/internationalization/#create-a-translation.

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to know how to translate it, I just need to find out how to customize that text via prop

Comment: "i just" again no way (The text come from the component). I hope you find simpler answer (Maybe open github issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading [source code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/fc948a559dc2947e484d869a8f4c276b6e79548f/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTableHeaderMobile.ts#L13) led me to this:
Html:
`:header-props="headerProps"`

Data:

```
headerProps: {
        sortByText: 'Custom sort by'
},
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/JafarAKhondali/pen/ExjdWpe?editable=true&editors=101)

But they should've documented it. I couldn't find it in their official documents either.